# How to disable mobile data for one of the sim

Tags: oneplus-two, oxygenos

I have a OnePlus 2 and have 2 sims in it. My question is how can I keep Mobile Data for SIM 1 on and off for SIM 2?

I have tried options in `SIM and network settings` but option to *enable/ disable* mobile data is in general setting and not in SIM specific settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There will be an option in Sim and Network settings mentioning "Default Sim for Internet". Choose the SIM 1

Comment: I have already done that but if there is no network for SIM 1, it uses SIM 2 for mobile data. I don't want this.